# How to create an aggregated table from an existing table using M language

Tags: powerbi, m, powerbi-desktop

I have a table - MemberJoin in Power BI which looks like below:

[image]

And I want to create an aggregated table from MemberJoin using M language. Is it doable? If yes, how to do it in M?

The corresponding SQL statement is below, and it's followed by a screenshot of what the new table should look like.

```js
select [YTD Flag], [Member Type], year([Join Date]) "Year",
       MONTH([Join Date]) "Month", datename(MONTH, [Join Date]) "MonthName",
       [Join Channel],  COUNT(*) "Count", 
       cast(count([YTD Flag]) as float) / cast(sum(count([YTD Flag])) 
        over (partition by year([Join Date])) as float) "Prcnt by Year"
from [MemberJoin]
group by [YTD Flag], [Member Type], [Join Channel], year([Join Date]), MONTH([Join Date]), datename(MONTH, [Join Date]) 
order by [YTD Flag] desc, [Member Type] desc, Year desc, Month, [Join Channel];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Group by command is on the Home ribbon of the Query editor. You can create a simple grouping, or more complex groupings with the Advanced option and adding more groupings and/or aggregations.

[image]